# can't pip install a branch

Tags: python, git, pip

I want to install this branch https://github.com/pathpy/pathpy/tree/plot which is a few commits ahead because I need some specific functions here. I am not sure how to pip install this branch and work with functions from there.

I tried `pip install git+https://github.com/pathpy/pathpy/tree/plot` but I get this error:

> WARNING: Discarding git+https://github.com/pathpy/pathpy/tree/plot. Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q https://github.com/pathpy/pathpy/tree/plot /private/var/folders/x9/qk9fwl9d6076z564bqhwmfj00000gn/T/pip-req-build-6r0fvozu Check the logs for full command output.
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q https://github.com/pathpy/pathpy/tree/plot /private/var/folders/x9/qk9fwl9d6076z564bqhwmfj00000gn/T/pip-req-build-6r0fvozu Check the logs for full command output.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bpip%5D+install+branch

Comment: `pip install git+https://github.com/pathpy/pathpy.git@plot`